# How to get all pairs of a set efficiently?

Tags: java, set

Given an object of a `Set`, I want to walk through all (unordered) pairs of it.

Example: Set = {1, 2, 3}, Pairs: (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3).

When dealing with a `Vector<Integer>`, one can achieve this with help of the index of each element:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
  for (int j = i + 1; j < vector.size(); j++)
    // Do something with vector.get(i) and vector.get(j)
```

But elements in a `Set<Integer>` have no indices.

The best solution, I found so far, is to convert the `Set` to a `Vector` and use the solution above.

Is there a more efficient / direct solution ?

Comment: You only need a vector/array in the nested loop. But other than that, I think this is the best solution.

Comment: @Jochen I think List is prefered solution

Comment: Actually, I'd go for an array, as the Set can produce one directly. But if you want a collection, then yes, use a list.

Comment: Thank you guys for the hint with the List and Array ! I will keep it in mind. A solution without converting seems not to be possible  without higher effort ?

Comment: Keep in mind that `Set`'s interface does not guarantee order. So the "index" value could change, especially if the `Set` is mutated.

Comment: See also functional solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345168/how-to-find-object-pairs-in-the-same-list-in-java-in-a-good-way

Answer (score 10):

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(mySet);
for (int i = 0; i < list .size(); i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < list .size(); j++)
        // Do something with vector.get(i) and vector.get(j)
```

Comment: Op said he need's to do the same thing with a set, he already know how to do with a list. #

Comment: Thank you. But as I already said, this solution works. Is there another one without converting (and maybe more efficient one) ?

Comment: How do you expect it to be more efficient, it would be of `O(n)`, so is the sample code.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of complexity for this algorithm = `n (n -1) / 2`, thus O(n^2) is the best you can  get (sequential).

Although, if your set is real big, a set that only fits in RAM. You can optimize the algorithm by calculating the pair in a block manner similar to what is done in matrix multiplication using tile blocks. This way you could reduce the % of cache miss and therefore increase the overall performance.

Besides that, you can introduce parallelization and divide work among thread/processes since the algorithm appears to be embarrassingly parallel.