# How to find object pairs in the same list in Java in a good way

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8

### **Init**

I have got an `ArrayList` with different objects. Im trying to search in the same list object pairs on the basic of a condition. If I found the right pairs Im creating a new object and adding it to a new list. But I want to avoid to create an object pair when objectA pairs with objectB and objectB pairs with objectA.

I didn't find a good way to do that until now.

### Ideas I tried

**2 for loops**

```
for(Object objectA : objectList){
    for(Object objectB : objectList){
        if(condition){
            // create new object
            // add to list
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: I need to kinda mark the already matched pairs, otherwise it will result in two created objects for the same pair which I want to avoid. It works, but probably isnt the best solution?

**Iterators**

Like the version with two forloops I used an iterator and removed the already matched object pair from the list. Works but doesnt seem that good?

**Java8 forEach & removeIf**

```
objectList.stream().forEach(posA -> {
    objectList.removeIf(posB -> condition);
});
```

Problem: When would I create my object pair object...?

### **Question**

Which is the best idea - or is there a better solution I didn't get?

Comment: Use basic for loops: `for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); ++i)` and `for (int j = i + 1; j < objectList.size(); ++j)`.

Comment: What do you mean by `pair` here exactly? Are you creating a 2D array and calling it a list of pairs or are you creating a class to hold pairs?

Comment: In the end these are just 2 objects I will match to a pair, its like a merge of two objects in my list. But if I match objectA with objectB, it will match also objectB with objectA, which results in another new object which I want to avoid...dont know if its clear.

Comment: Can you post a simple input / output of what you want? It isn't clear what you're asking.

Comment: If you need to "kinda mark the already matched pairs", then, well, do that? Create some sort of boolean list that stores if the object at the same position was already used?

Comment: @Aziuth I did and it works, I just thought there is probably a nicer solution to this problem.

Comment: Another question, can there be more than one match? Can there be a, b, c so that a,b and a,c are matches? If not, I guess the only thing you fear is that a,b and b,a are found. If so, why don't you do it like Andy Turner proposed?

Comment: As @Aziuth has asked is important to be clear about how many matches are possible otherwise the description of the algorithm is incomplete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently you consider an unordered pair where pair(a,b) is the same as pair(b,a). You have to create a class for this purpose yourself, e.g.

```
class Pair<T> {
    final T a, b;

    public Pair(T a, T b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj==this) return true;
        if(!(obj instanceof Pair)) return false;
        Pair<?> p=(Pair<?>)obj;
        return Objects.equals(this.a, p.a) && Objects.equals(this.b, p.b)
            || Objects.equals(this.a, p.b) && Objects.equals(this.b, p.a);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(a) + Objects.hashCode(b);
    }
}
```

Having a class bearing the desired semantic, you can simply create all combinations and let the Stream API remove duplicates. This will even work, if the source list already has duplicates:

```
List<YourNewObjectType> result = objectList.stream()
    .flatMap(objA -> objectList.stream().map(objB -> new Pair<>(objA,objB)))
    .distinct()
    .filter(pair -> condition)
    .map(pair -> new YourNewObjectType … )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You didn’t specify whether an element is allowed to be paired with itself. If not, you may filter these cases out:

```
List<YourNewObjectType> result = objectList.stream()
    .flatMap(objA -> objectList.stream()
        .filter(objB -> !Objects.equals(objA, objB))
        .map(objB -> new Pair<>(objA,objB)))
    .distinct()
    .filter(pair -> condition)
    .map(pair -> new YourNewObjectType … )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As a side note, if the construction of your result type is side effect free and not expensive and the type has an equality which reflects the two input elements, you may consider constructing them instead of the `Pair` instances and use `.distinct` for them, saving the conversion of `Pair` instances to `YourNewObjectType` instances.

If your source list is free of duplicates, you can utilize this knowledge to build unique pairs based on the indices:

```
List<YourNewObjectType> result = IntStream.range(0, objectList.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> IntStream.range(i/*+1*/, objectList.size())
        .mapToObj(j -> new Pair<>(objectList.get(i),objectList.get(j))))
    .flatMap(Function.identity())
    .filter(pair -> condition)
    .map(pair -> new YourNewObjectType … */)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If pairing an element with itself is not allowed, just turn the `/*+ 1*/` comment to a real `+1`. This code is less readable, but potentially more efficient.

Comment: This is very inefficient!

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera: define “very”. It’s simple and it depends on the unspecified aspects of the task, like if the list can contain duplicates, whether there is a more efficient solution at all. You are welcome to post your better solution.

Comment: If You think in a list with 1000 elements, you are creating near to a millon of pairs!

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera: you might be surprised, how little the costs of a million temporary lightweight objects actually are. Sure, if there is a way to avoid them, you may go that way, however, there are prerequisites, like having no duplicates in the source list.

Comment: sure it surprises me and the most probable is the list will contain few elements. but It is an O(n^2) space complexity algorithm, IMHO It is not the best choice.

Comment: @David Pérez Cabrera: these `n²` pairs are not alive at the same time. Only the distinct pairs are. The space actually occupied by the others depends on the JVM, it may be as small as a single element…

Comment: _these n² pairs are not alive at the same time._ Today is a great day to learn something new. Thank you.

Comment: @Holger I actually like this. Well no solution I already tried is really efficient, therefore its not that important. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 3):

As @AndyTurner said, I think this is the best way for `ArrayList` implementation of `objectList`:

```
    boolean[] removed = new boolean[objectList.size()];
    Arrays.fill(removed, false); // unnecessary
    List<Pair> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
        if (!removed[i]) {
            Object objectA = objectList.get(i);
            for (int j = i + 1; j < objectList.size(); j++) {
                if (!removed[j]) {
                    Object objectB = objectList.get(j);
                    if (condition) {
                        removed[j] = true;
                        result.add(new Pair(objectA, objectB));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will throw a ConcurrentModificationException at runtime

Comment: @Matt no! It won't,

Comment: @Holger You are right, I thought it was a requirement, but it isn't. Edited

Comment: `removed[j] = true` is broken. each element could apper in all pairs only **once**

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera this is a solution I did, except that I used the java5 for loop and added the already matched pairs into a new list and checked everytime with a contains (which was def. bad and not as good as ur solution). thank you for your effort, good solution imo.

Comment: @Sergey why is broken? If the external loop ends with a matched objectA then this element is implicitly removed because index j starts from i+1. A matched objectB instead is explictly removed with removed[j] = true and it will not be considered for future comparison neither as objectA nor as objectB.

Answer (score 1):

Why non-functional approach is not acceptable?

```
List<Pair<Object, Object>> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < objectList.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < objectList.size(); j++) {
        if (condition) {
            pairs.add(new Pair<>(objectList.get(i), objectList.get(j)));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the list can be ordered, another approach could be:

- sort the list

Loop:

- iterate using iterators, removing the object scanned
- launch a binary search for the element that pairs with the one you just removed
- remove that element and create your custom object with those two elements

This way you can reduce the time complexity of the research from O(N^2) to O(nlogn).